# Window onbeforeunload just displays the conformation message but cannot be triggered to function called in it

Tags: javascript

Window onbeforeunload just displays the conformation message but cannot be triggered to function called in it. Conformation Message is showing in Chrome, Safari But not in Mozilla.

I tried the below code:

```
function submitform(){
  $('#appstrm').submit();
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
 submitform();
 var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
 e.returnValue = dialogText;
 return dialogText;
};
```

In Chrome, Safari Only the conformation Popup appears But the sumbitform() is not triggered. In Mozilla, No conformation Popup appears. Please suggest and thanx in advance

Comment: What you are trying to do is basically impossible.... Modern browsers prevent the http requests from fire when the page is exiting.

Comment: Yes I understood it But I need to capture the user results when the window is closed or refreshed. Is there any way to capture?

Answer (score 0):

form.submit() is asynchronous operation which handover his control to other child thread and proceeds to next inline operation, performs that operation and without waiting for asynchronous operation to complete killed main thread and main thread in result kill child threads.

try to make submit() method synchronous by using `deffered` to make promise and in `then` of returned promise call your Show Dialogue operation.

https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library to achieve your desired results. If the user leaves the page, you can perform a message alert to stop the page from redirecting. HTH!

I tend to use a library to help me out : https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure/

Usage:

```
$(function () {
    // used to find any form on the page
    $('form').areYouSure(
      {
          message: 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                 + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.'
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: This works fine but Once the page is totally loaded it must show conformation when the window is closed or refreshed.  areYouSure plugin works fine. But i cannot capture the every window refresh or window close.